# Very long "Router Dispatch" in Clockwork with Laravel 4 on localhost

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, url-routing, dispatch, clockwork

I've got a Laravel app setup locally with (what seems to me) very poor performance as you can see below:

[image: Laravel 4 time line with Clockwork]

**My setup:**

- W8 on a pretty fast laptop with SSD
- XAMPP 3.2.1
- Laravel 4.1.*
- Clockwork 1.* (only added the controller event as desribed in the docs)
- Debug mode true

**The scenario described:**

- A logged in user access a page with a list of prospects : **1216ms**
- Then the user logs out : **1164ms**
- Finally the user is redirected to the login page : **1165ms**

As you can see in every single request the bottleneck is the "Router Dispatch" event. What can I do to dig further, and most importantly what can I do to improve its duration?

Or maybe because this is a dev environnment these are expected numbers? (I don't believe so, but I might be wrong).

Comment: Try a clean install of Laravel and see if the problem continues. If it solves it, then remove sections of your app until you find the code that is causing the issue...

Comment: @TheShiftExchange on a fresh install: 80ms and 130ms with Clockwork but on another test app (a one page, one controller, no DB, no auth, ...) I did several weeks ago: 150ms / 1200ms! So I thought I could try to disable Clockwork but unforntunately it didn't change anything on the current app I'm working on. Anyways I was more looking for help on how to output the durations of all the "Router Dispatch" sub elements (like the "Controller running." line). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating my XAMPP to the latest and Laravel to 4.2, this just got fixed by itself.